# Cannot read property 'classList' of null in forEach from volume-indicator

Tags: javascript, sdk, agora.io

I'm adding a 'speaking' class to show a border when the user is speaking.
When I speaking, the code working:

```
 if (options.uid == volume.uid && volume.level > volumeLevel) {
    document.getElementById(options.uid).classList.add("speaking");
  }else if (options.uid == volume.uid && volume.level < volumeLevel) {
    document.getElementById(options.uid).classList.remove("speaking");
  }
```

But other users in other pages, get a error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

```
if(options.uid != volume.uid && volume.level > volumeLevel) {
   document.getElementById(options.uid).classList.add("speaking");
 }else if (options.uid != volume.uid && volume.level < volumeLevel) {
   document.getElementById(options.uid).classList.remove("speaking");
 }
```

**Full code**

```
var volumeLevel=15; 
  rtc.on("volume-indicator", volumes => {
    volumes.forEach((volume) => {
      if (options.uid == volume.uid && volume.level > volumeLevel) {
        document.getElementById(options.uid).classList.add("speaking");
      }else if (options.uid == volume.uid && volume.level < volumeLevel) {
        document.getElementById(options.uid).classList.remove("speaking");
      }
      if (options.uid != volume.uid && volume.level > volumeLevel) {
        document.getElementById(options.uid).classList.add("speaking");
      }else if (options.uid != volume.uid && volume.level < volumeLevel) {
        document.getElementById(options.uid).classList.remove("speaking");
      }
    });
  })
```

Comment: What is placed inside the options variable and how is it placed? Did you check if it is null? Maybe it does not exist on your page (options.uid).

Comment: Issue solved. Thanks ;)

Comment: Might be worthwhile to post the solution to your problem as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `options.uid` isn't on the DOM if `document.getElementById()` is returning `null`

Comment: I'm adding the content using innerHTML. var speakers=document.getElementById("speakers"); //div with all speakers speakers.innerHTML+=html

Comment: Issue solved. Thanks ;)